# How to conditionally compile (using Grunt) only changed jade files with template includes

Tags: javascript, compilation, pug, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Using a version of what `grunt-contrib-watch` recommends for compiling only changed files *in here*: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#compiling-files-as-needed

```
var changedFiles = Object.create(null);

var onChange = grunt.util._.debounce(function() {
grunt.config('jshint.all.src', Object.keys(changedFiles));
   changedFiles = Object.create(null);
}, 200);

grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
   changedFiles[filepath] = action;
   onChange();
});
```

This works fine (again with a variation I wrote for it here: https://gist.github.com/pgilad/6897875)

**The problem** is when using `include` inside Jade templates, meaning you are including other Jade templates in order to build the complete html file.

Using the singular solution for compile doesn't work because if a `.jade` file you are working on is embeded using `include current_working_jade.jade` - the **including file** won't get recompiled.

Are there any workarounds for this ***besides*** compiling all of your `jade` files from scratch? This causes a problem when you have around ~60 large jade files to compile every time.

The only possible solution I can think of is either mapping jade templates dependencies either externally or with directories, but I don't know any tools/plugins which do that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After already starting to work on a scaffold that will generate a sortof jade `sourcemap` I found this great project, that already solves this issue:

[Jade Inheritance](https://github.com/paulyoung/jade-inheritance)

Usage is as follows:

1. Install package using: `npm install jade-inheritance --save-dev`
2. Where you want to get a list of dependent files from a jade:

   `var JadeInheritance = require('jade-inheritance');`

   `var inheritance = new JadeInheritance(file, basedirname, {basedir:basedirname});`
3. Then when you want to get the file:

   `depenedentFiles = inheritance.files;`
4. The project also demonstrates how to apply the concept with `grunt.watch` in order to compile only changed `jade` files with their dependents, exactly what I needed:

**[Using jade-inheritance with grunt watch](https://github.com/paulyoung/jade-inheritance#integration-with-grunt-contrib-jade)**

Comment: Can this work for multi folder, inherited files as we debug it we can't set  as it works, will appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I imagine something like checking all jade files and if they include your changed file then recompile that as well. Shouldn't be too hard. Pseudo code:

```
var allFiles = getAllJadeFileWithIncludesAndProjectPathMap();
//allFiles now contains something like this

{
  'jade/index.jade': ['jade/menu.jade', 'jade/home.jade'],
  'jade/about.jade': ['jade/menu.jade']
}


var rootFiles = [];

_.each(allFiles, function (includes, parent) {
  _.each(includes, function (includePath) {
    var parent;
    while (parent = getParentPath(includePath)) {
      //nothing needed if getParentPath returns null for files that aren't included
    }

    if (rootFiles.indexOf(parent) !== -1) {
      rootFiles.push(parent);
    }
  });
});
```

Now add these files to the compile task.

Comment: Hmm, the `getAllJadeFileWithIncludesAndProjectPathMap()` is actually what I was looking for. So basically after getting a `changed` event - I find it in the `Array` and compile the `jade` and all of it's children.. Not only that, but I was looking for an already existing solution, and didn't want to invent the wheel myself.